# SQL Resource Waits - Buffer I/O - PAGEIOLATCH_SH

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, activity-monitor

I am not a DBA, but have recently been charged with monitoring my companies DB.  A merge that normally takes 12-18 minutes is now taking over 2 hours.  This was setup by a DBA and I am told that all the indexing was done correctly.  I found in the activity monitor that the process is hitting a PAGEIOLATCH_SH/EX wait type and the Resource Waits - Buffer I/O wait times are above 3000 (I cant find a baseline to see if this is normal...but it doesn't seem to be).  Does anyone have any information on where I could go from here?  I have already tried restarting the SQL server and force re-compiling the stored procedure that calls the merge. We are not working with an massive DB only about 2 million rows or so.

Comment: Are you sure the pageio wait is really responsible for making it run for 2 hours? No disk I know of is that slow (though that it took 12-18 minutes in the first place may be telling) - have you checked during its progress to see if it's also being blocked?

Comment: It is actually running as we speak. I am not sure how to know if the pageio is directly related to the increase in time but the merge does sit in suspended with the pageio wait type on it.

Comment: Well sounds like ludicrously underwhelming disk performance, but again, not anywhere near enough information for us to be able to solve. You can see a single session's wait stats accumulate with an extended events session filtered on spid, but you should also monitor sys.dm_exec_requests for blocking against that session. Again, if a MERGE takes two hours, sounds like something is much more fundamentally wrong than just slow disks. Also, in case you're infatuated with MERGE, [please read this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Comment: I also noticed that the merge seems to complete in about the same time as before (12 mins) because SQL's processor time drops off, but then the merge sits in suspended with the wait time on it for another hour and a half or more.  Also this has been increasing in time for a month now, creeping up a few minutes a day.

Comment: As Aaron said, there is not enough information here. He has requested information from you and it's your turn to provide it. Voting to close. Please reopen if necessary once the needed information is here.